# Create higher order instance for a list of a type where the instance for type exists

Tags: haskell, typeclass, higher-kinded-types

I'm not sure this is possible. I have something like the following class:

```
data Bar a = Bar1 a | Bar2

class Foo f where
  foo :: f a -> Either [String] a

instance Foo Bar where
  foo (Bar1 x) = Right x
  foo Bar2 = Left ["is Bar2"]
```

Now I want to be able to define an instance that given an implementation for `Foo f` implement `Foo [f]`.

So something like this:

```
data Bar a = Bar1 a | Bar2

class Foo f where
  foo :: f a -> Either [String] a

instance Foo Bar where
  foo (Bar1 x) = Right x
  foo Bar2 = Left ["is Bar2"]

instance Foo f => Foo [f] where
  foo as = foldr reducer (Right []) (foo <$> as)
    where
      reducer (Right n) (Right xs) = Right $ n:xs
      reducer (Left xs) (Right _)  = Left xs
      reducer (Right _) (Left xs)  = Left xs
      reducer (Left xs) (Left ys)  = Left $ xs ++ ys
```

Where the list instance just accumulates all lefts and if there no lefts it removes the outer list and moves it to the right (can this be written implemented easier?). The instance like this doesn't type check since the type isn't `[f] a` but `[f a]`. The type I expect is `foo :: [f a] -> Either [String] [a]`

I tried to write a type that this does for me:

```
type ApplyList (f :: Type -> Type) (a :: Type) = [f a]

instance Foo f => Foo (ApplyList f) where
...
```

But this doesn't work because I guess types do not support currying.

Is there a way to write this correctly?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you add the type of `foo` you expect for your instance? E.g. something like `foo :: Foo f => f [a] -> Either [String] a` ? Or what? (Further, I'm pretty sure you don't want `[f]`, which is a rather advanced thing in Haskell due to DataKinds -- and is not a type, e.g. `[f] a` is ill-kinded.)

Comment: @chi That's the problem. `[f] a` is ill kinded. The type I'm looking for is `[f a]`.

Comment: I don't think you can have `foo :: [f a] -> Either [String] [a]` with your class: your class makes the return type to be `Either [String] a` which does not depend on `f`, so that can't be changed in the instances. You'll probably need some changes in your class definition, maybe adding another parameter `a` to the class, so that it can later be instantiated to `[a]`. Maybe with some fundep (or type family?).

Comment: In the instance you are trying to write you can return a list of `a`, but the class says you can return only at most one `a`. So you should rethink what abstraction this type class stands for. One `a` or many `a`? Does that depend on `f`?

Answer (score 2):

I ended up changing my class to have the fully applied input and output type. It's a little bit clunky but it works.

```
class Foo f g where
  foo :: f -> Either [String] g

instance Foo (Bar a) a where
  foo (Bar1 x) = Right x
  foo Bar2 = Left ["is Bar2"]

instance Foo f g => Foo [f] [g] where
  foo as = foldr reducer (Right []) (foo <$> as)
    where
      reducer (Right n) (Right xs) = Right $ n:xs
      reducer (Left xs) (Right _)  = Left xs
      reducer (Right _) (Left xs)  = Left xs
      reducer (Left xs) (Left ys)  = Left $ xs ++ ys
```